# How is button connected in asp.net MVC app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an asp.net MVC app.  There is a `<button>` in a .cshtml file.  The button only has an `id`.  There isn't any javascript associated with it.  I don't see this button name in any of the controllers.

Yet, when the button is clicked, it doesn't perform an action.  How do I trace down what is triggering the button action once it is clicked?

Comment: " it doesn't perform an action"? Does not align with the rest of the question... Sample HTML can help (also I suspect it is default "submit" button).

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is not Web Forms. Buttons do not automatically trigger a `Click` event in your code.

Comment: As Alexei said, this is probably a "submit" button, whereas in your code is found `@Html.BeginForm()` or the like. The cshtml view code would be necessary to see what it's all about.

Comment: It **doesn't** perform an action or it **does** perform an action?

Comment: @CodeCaster `<button />` has `type=submit` by default... http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/button

Comment: @Alexei wow, that has changed, I'll remove my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are a little confused on how ASP.NET `WebForm` and `MVC` works.

While `WebForm` is very much similar to `WinForms` , in a sense that controls can have events that gives it a sense of Stateful appearance, `MVC` is not the same, it **embraces** the `stateless` nature of HTTP.

In `MVC` when a button is clicked, it is usually associated with a `controller`and a `action` to which it posts the data. So, a button click is translated to action on a control same like method invocation in a `WebForm`.

---

***Q. The controller still needs to know about the button to handle the click?***

---

there is no existence of control on server side, its the downside (+side from my view) of being stateless. **In MVC there is no click**, but only method invocation on the controllers.

A same action can be invoked using 10 different buttons. If u can share the code of `<view>.cshtml` then may be I can help a little bit more.

Comment: The controller still needs to know about the button to handle the click.

Comment: @4thSpace please edit the question to align with accepted answer. Should be something along the lines "how ASP.Net MVC works compared to WebForms" rather than why particular button does/does not do something.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov How is it any different?  It's the same result.  Besides, it won't do anything for the down votes.

Comment: That was my original point of view.  You're asking me to add info into the question now that others have contributed additional info.  If I posted questions and kept modifying them based on all the additional info in comments and answers provided, no one will ever know what the original question was.  It can also make the comments/answers confusing or even irrelevant.  I really don't care about the down votes.  You get them by default.

Answer (score 1):

There could be java script in a separate file. In that JavaScript file there must be click handler attached that must be calling your action in controller via whatever mechanism.

To begin with .. Search in your project where else that button id is used.
That could be the point where you can start tracing...

Answer (score 0):

By virtue of the button being defined within the Html.BeginForm braces, the button click is wired to perform a POST submission with the form data.

Comment: If you don't want the button to submit you can can always add a onSubmit = "return MyValidator()" to your BeginForm and then build a javascript function that only returns true if certain conditions exist.